# failed to get correct parameters while downloading the meeting component

Tags: google-chrome, cisco, webex

When I am trying to open Webex from my PC, I am getting this error :

failed to get correct parameters while downloading the meeting component

[image]

I have tried looking into CISCO community but no answers are present.

Please help me out since I am unable to join some important meetings.

PS - I tried joining the meeting from my Roommate's Laptop & I am able to connect Webex. Looks like something is wrong in my PC

Comment: https://help.webex.com/en-us/WBX9000023909/Error-Failed-to-get-correct-parameters-while-downloading-the-meeting-component-Contact-Technical-Support-for-assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this thing :
open setting --> search 'proxy' -->select 'open proxy settings' --> Go to advanced tab in internet properties --> tick mark all SSL & TLS checboxes

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]